# Change color of parent div's color on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html code like below

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <span class="span1"></span>
```

If the span with class="span1" has no value between begining and ending tags, I would like to change the color of div with class="class1"

However, span is filled with javascript after loading, so should I change the color with JS or CSS? Can anybody show me a way to do it?

I dont have any sample code to display because I am not sure how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if specified element has nothing between tags, use `html()` function provided by `jQuery`. To change parent's style, use `parent()` and `css()` functions. To wait until the DOM is loaded, use `ready()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('.span1').html()) {
    $('.span1').parent().css({ color: 'red' });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">text
    <span class="span1"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("span1")[0].parentElement.parentElement.style.color = "green";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "go up the dom" by css, only down, so you has to do it with js. Here is som sample code:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".span1").each(function(){
      if($(this).html() == ""){
          $(this).closest(".class1").css("background-color", "red")
      }
   })
})
```

```css
span{
  height: 10px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <span class="span1"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <span class="span1">filled</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing via jQuery using different functions css(),parents(),html().

You need to put your all code inside this $(document).ready() So this will be execute after all DOM data loaded.

For that You just need to use below code:

Html code:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        Hello this is test message.
        <span class="span1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".span1").html().toString().length > 0 ? $(".span1").parents(".class1").css("background-color","red") : $(".class1").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
```

First we check the length if it's grater 0 then it will execute this

```
$(".span1").parents(".class1").css("background-color","red")
```

otherwise this:

```
$(".class1").css("background-color","yellow");
```

Here i have set background color using parents and you can directly apply via class name.

I hope this code will help you.